# IdentityServer 4 Authentication Event in Client

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, razor-pages, asp.net-core-identity

I have an IdentityServer 4 server set up as a stand-alone app, using net core 3.1, Entity Framework core against MySql and Net Core Identity as a user store. Separately I have a Razor Pages client app, which authenticates against the Identity Server, with user logon taking place on the server. All this is working fine.

I now wish to be able to write a log entry on the client for any new user authentication or failed logon. I assume there must be events raised somewhere.  How do I go about this, please?

Comment: Any reason you want logs on the client, not the auth server? There are [events](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/events.html) raised on IdentityServer for that. A failed login wouldn't be returned to the client anyways because it didn't happen there, unless you capture it and send it to the client somehow.

Comment: Yes, mainly for audit purposes. Obviously one could read the logs side-by-side but much less convenient and effective.

Comment: Just some ideas, you could add an endpoint on the razor client and post the events from identity server over to the razor client. Or you could add a middleware to the client that checks the requests for some parameter appended to the ReturnUrl or the auth server referrer.

Comment: Only reliable one I think is server to client communication; posting the event from one to the other. You won't get duplicate events from someone navigating back or something.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same requirement, to store for example authentication failure in audit log - if someone tried to access api with invalid token.

What I found is that `IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions` has `JwtBearerEvents` property which can be used to be notified about such events.

In my case it worked this way:

```cs
.AddAuthentication(AUTH_SCHEME).AddIdentityServerAuthentication(AUTH_SCHEME, options => {
    options.ApiName = config.ApiName;
    options.Authority = config.Address;
    options.JwtBearerEvents = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnAuthenticationFailed = c =>
        {
            // Log can bo done here
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnTokenValidated = c =>
        {
            // Log can bo done here
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnChallenge = c =>
        {
            // Log can bo done here
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnForbidden = c =>
        {
            // Log can bo done here
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
    options.SupportedTokens = SupportedTokens.Jwt;});
```

I was afraid that it will override normal IS behavior, but everything seems to work as it used to.

You have access to proper contexts there, for example in `JwtBearerChallengeContext` you can read `Error` or `ErrorDescription` strings or even whole `HttpContext`.